# How to make horizontal overflow for table inside a div?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am trying to bring the scroll bar to bottom so that all tables should display when I scroll horizontally.
I tried many steps but not able to achieve it.

Here is the code - [JSFiddle](https://codepen.io/rushmedev/pen/NWROjav)

I have tried following code but not able to achieve it.

```
overflow-x: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Here is an image what I want to achieve.
[image]

```html
<div style="width: 750px; height: 321px; overflow-x: auto;">
  <table align="left" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 200px; height: 85px">Demo
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table align="left" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 200px; height: 85px">Demo
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table align="left" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 200px; height: 85px">Demo
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table align="left" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 200px; height: 85px">Demo
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table align="left" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 200px; height: 85px">Demo
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 24px">12 (0)</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Put all data into one table. Or set width to inner content (if possible). There is no `don't wrap at the right edge of page` rule in CSS.

Comment: a minimal reproduciabel code snippet has to be added to the question. If the codepen link would change or your would clsoe your project, then this question would hold no further community value. As such a codepen link might be added to provide a full code access but not to replace a minimal reproduciable code snippet.

Comment: the issue is the `<div style="width: 750px; height: 321px; overflow-x: auto;">` which is to small `width-wise`. You having 5 tables with 200px width each. This equals a width of 1,000px. So you missing 250px width for your div. Takign the invisible border into account you actually need to change the line to: `<div style="width: 1010px; overflow-x: auto;">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed nearly all your `inline-style` and re-added them as `css-style`. This makes the code way shorter and easier.

you have 5 tables within your div-wrapper. Each table has a width of 200px. So you need to enlarge the wrapping div width to 1000px. 750px would not allow to contain 5 tables with 200px each. You are missing 250px width. This causes 2 of the tables to drop down below the first 3 tables.

Last but not least, I gave the tables the property: `box-sizing: border box;`. That way you dont have to calculate the paddings and border thickness. Otherwise you would need a wrappign div width of 1010px to take the 5x left + right borders with 1px each into account.

```css
.table-wrapper {
  min-width: 1000px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table-wrapper * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

th {
  width: 200px;
  height: 85px;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 750px; overflow-x: auto;">
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <table align="left" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Demo</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table align="left" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Demo</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table align="left" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Demo</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table align="left" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Demo</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table align="left" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Demo</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12 (0)</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```